# Sharepoint Custom WebPart 2007- Target Audience Missing

Tags: web-part, audience-targeting

I have created a site in SP 2007 and its of type Teamsite. I have created a webpart and I want it to target for a group and unfortunately I cannot see target Audience Text box for that Webpart, What silly mistake have I done?

This is the Image of the Webpart when I try to edit it..

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Just to verify; is it WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 1):

Target Audience property only available with MOSS or Server edition. So ensure the SharePoint you are using is WSS or MOSS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone tried to assist me, but the actual problem in my case was -  I forgot to activate the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature.  Once activated it, It came back.

Comment: Is this account yours too? [1737](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1737) I can merge them for you...